# Typescript compiler throw error in vue library

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue3, Typescript, and Symfony project, if I want to use a top level await in the script setup for triggering the suspense, when compiling typescript throw this error

```
      TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'withAsyncContext'.
```

Here some information about my file:

view

```
let urls = [
    '/protected/api/inps/indennita'
];

const requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));

//todo migliorare il legame url-risorsa-operazioni
await axios.all(requests).then((responses) => {

    // /protected/api/inps/indennita
    let response = responses[0]
    indennitaData.table = response.data

});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <Modal/>
    <ConfirmationModal/>

    <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <suspense timeout="0">
            <template #default>
                <component :is="Component" :key="$route.fullPath"/>
            </template>
            <template #fallback>
                <div>Loading...</div>
            </template>
        </suspense>
    </router-view>
</template>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "encore production --progress",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.28",
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.23.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

When I try to use the same top level await in a new fresh Vue 3 project with typescript, this error does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone using Vue + Typescript + Symfony and you face this Typescript error when compiling here it is the solution that solved my problem.

I have update my package.json to this

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "encore production --progress",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.28",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.23.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

I have updated the Vue version and installed the "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin"

```
yarn add fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
```

and added this in webpack config

```
  .enableForkedTypeScriptTypesChecking()
```

Comment: That worked for me working with Laravel Mix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a misunderstanding in your script, and the working of async api call.

**Javascript have two way for waiting the api call.** 
If we take a random function named getUsers who does a GET api request we might assign the value like this:

```
created() {
  getUsers.then(response => {
   const users = response.users
  })
}
```

In the lifecyclehook `created` i get my users and assign them after the response come back, the `then()` is only execute after the api request end.

You can do exactly the same with the `await` method:

```
async created() {
 const response = await getUsers()
 const users = response.users
}
```

You say to the methods `created` that it's a `async` methods, with that you just have to execute your action and await for the response. 
The line:

```
const response = await getUsers()
```

Stop the execution of the script and await the response from the api, the second line is executed only after the api request is done.

The two methods do the job, the second with `await` is more easy to read and a best practice.

Comment: Hi @Raphael Rlt, I have already tried to use a lifecycle hook vue, like onMounted, the error disappear but the suspense is not triggered

Comment: I details like this because i think you don't understand who you need to use await and because the problem you have is not really clear.
What does you mean by "suspense is not triggered"?

Comment: with suspense i mean the vue 3 component, https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html. Basically this component render a fallback component when his child ( the view) does an async call, using the script setup and an await in it. In my example, when there is an await, the suspense render "Loading..."